# How to find the source line in which a async nodejs program fails

Tags: node.js, error-handling, q

I have an error in my nodejs code which involves uploading files in parallel to a AWS Bucket using [q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q). Somewhere in the code an error is produced. I have no Idea where.

**The concrete situation:**
I have a simple nodejs script that uploads all files in the current directory to an aws bucket and return a "q" promise of the result:

```
var uploadAll = function() {
    var uploadFiles = readdirRecursiveSync(".");

    var uploadPromises = uploadFiles.map(function(fileName) {
        var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucketName } });
        var file = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        return Q.denodeify(bucket.upload)({ Body: file, Key: fileName});
    });
    return Q.all(uploadPromises);
}

uploadAll().then(function(){
  console.log("done");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Now, when I do this I get an error which reads like this:

```
[TypeError: self.service.constructor.__super__ is not a function]
```

But I have no Idea how to find the source line that produces this error.

I tried running the script with

```
node debug script.js
```

But that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to enable Q's long stack trace support if you want to find the source line that actually produces the error:

```
Q_DEBUG=1 node script.js
```

But I can already tell you that the problem is that the `bucket.upload` method requires that the context (`this`) is `bucket`. So you'll need to bind that method to `bucket`.

```
var uploadAll = function() {
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: bucketName } });
    var bucketUpload = Q.nbind(bucket.upload, bucket);
    return Q.all(readdirRecursiveSync(".").map(function(fileName) {
        var file = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        return bucketUpload({ Body: file, Key: fileName });
    }));
}
```